# Bluemix Cors disable Node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cors, ibm-cloud

I am not able to avoid this error on my browser - **XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xyz.mybluemix.net/get_user_byId.Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://a.x.y.z:9000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.**

I am using every measure required to actually allow cross origin calls, but still it gives me an error.

```
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
    next();
});

app.get('/get_users', cors(), function(req, res) {...}
```

I am calling this api like - (standard $http angular way)

```
return $http.post(base+"get_user_byId", id)
```

Comment: maybe there is a *CORS CONFIG* in bluemix, like in aws

Answer (score 0):

You need only:

```
var cors = require('cors'); //Importing this middleware enables CORS
```

and

```
app.use(cors());
```

to allow CORS in express/connect applications

*Delete these lines:*

```
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
    next();
});
```

and set your GET API with:

```
app.get('/get_users', function(req, res) {...}
```

- Reference - Enable all CORS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#simple-usage-enable-all-cors-requests

In angularJS you have to call that API with GET method (no post) because you have defined /get_users api with get method.

I suggest you to use this snippet:

```
      var par = {
        id: myId,
      };
     var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
     app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

        $http({
            method : "GET",
            params: par,
            url : base + "/get_users"
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.myData = response.data;
        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.myData = response.statusText;
        });

});
```

Comment: So I did all the changes you mention but, I still get this errors

Comment: angular.js:9827 OPTIONS http://xyz.mybluemix.net/add_user (anonymous function) @ angular.js:9827sendReq @ angular.js:9628serverRequest @ angular.js:9344processQueue @ angular.js:13189(anonymous function) @ angular.js:13205Scope.$eval @ angular.js:14401Scope.$digest @ angular.js:14217Scope.$apply @

Comment: angular.js:14506(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16232completeOutstandingRequest @ angular.js:4905(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5285
welcome.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xyz.mybluemix.net/add_user. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 502